# jquery navigate to another page and load a php page into a div

Tags: jquery, load, window.location

```
//i am trying to press an href   
<div id="block-left">
<a href="#serv/compA">Company Administration</a>
```

and i want to click on href and
first i want to go to page services.php
and then load to the div="serv-content"
the page from href.

//this the script i am trying

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#block-left a").click(function() {
    var page= this.hash.substr(1);
    window.location("services.php");
    $("#serv-content").load(page);
  });
  return false;
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You no need to call window.location, id.load will take care the dynamic content load. Use the below code, it will helpful for you.

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
        function loadContent() {
        $("#serv-content").load("http://sitename.com/services.php", function() {
            alert("Done");                
        });
        }

        $("#block-left a").click(loadContent);
        loadContent();
    });
```

Comment: thanks for your response what is the #actions, and why i have to declare the #ser-content to load?